# discoloration of images created by ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

I m converting a pdf into image using ghostscript

It almost produces good images but for one pdf the created image is having a white strip

however this strip is not present in the original pdf.

script which i hv used is below

gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=2 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=fileName.gif -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q pdfName.pdf -c quit

Here the created image http://www.pictureshack.us/images/65486_1.gif

i am using Ghostscript 8.70 and the issue is fixed for the latest update i.e 9.06, but i cant upgrade to this...moreover found the issue its due -r300, so when i specify resolution of 100 then it works fine for this pdf but not for many other pdf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using, and you haven't provided the original PDF file, so I can't test it on current code. However, this 'looks like' a transparency bug, and may well be fixed in recent versions of Ghostscript.

I would suggest you upgrade to 9.06 if you haven't already and try that. If the problem persists please open a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com Please attach the original PDF file and the command line you are using.

Comment: well i am using Ghostscript 8.70 and the issue is fixed for the latest update i.e 9.06, but i cant upgrade to this...